# My light in bedroom isn’t working

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

So my light recently went out so obviously checked bulbs and then Bought a new led fixture which worked fine but then it stopped working as well so wiring it I notice the light will light up but only when neutral fixture wire is wired to ground but not black-black white-white and ground/ground, I checked continuity from switch to fixture in both and it’s fine also get 120 with hot/gnd hot-neutral gets no reading any help will be appreciated, also all other electrical on this circuit is working

Comment: Please try to edit some punctuation into your 'question'.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you've done a pretty good job diagnosing the problem - *neutral broken*.

A regular (as opposed to "smart") switch only gets hot, which is why it looks just fine. Lights/switches are normally wired one of two ways:

- Panel -> Switch -> Light

In this case, the switch box should have two white wires in it - one coming from the panel and one from the light switch - normally connected together with a wire nut. Depending on what else is in the box (other switches, receptacles, pass-through loads) there may be a whole bundle of neutrals, one of which should be (but likely isn't) connecting to the light fixture.

- Panel -> Light -> Switch

This is a *switch loop*. In this case, black hot (from the panel) will connect to white going down to the switch. The switch gets white (hot) and black (switched hot) in the same cable and black goes up to the light fixture.

In either case, there is a problem with the neutral (white) wire *somewhere*. It could be in the switch box (my best guess) but could be in a *previous* box in the circuit, or could even be at the panel if this light is the first and/or only item in the circuit.

There is a small possibility that the problem is in the middle of a wire hidden in a wall. But far more common is a loose or broken connection in a junction box.

Comment: Thank you for helping me track it down, it ended up being a neutral on a gfci that broke

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. One point regarding GFCI: Hard-wired lights, except for lights above bathtubs/showers, generally do **not** need to be on GFCI. So if you have a branch of a circuit that goes from a GFCI *only* to hard-wired lights (and their switches) then it should pigtail off the *LINE* side rather than the *LOAD* side. That way, if (classic example) a device plugged in to the receptacle in a bathroom gets wet and trips the GFCI, the lights don't turn off at the same time.

Comment: If you'll take the [tour], @Fearless13, you'll note that the proper way to say "thanks" is to click the up vote arrow _and_ to click the check mark. This lets others know that the answer has been found.